# Express route for angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have created an express angular app which works fine but if I am at a URL say http://localhost:4007/login and hit refresh it gets an error tried many things to correct it nothing works.

My server snippet code is as follow.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/bringclean')));;

app.get('/*', function (req, res){
    res.redirect('/');
});
app.listen(4007, function () {
  console.log('BringClean app is running on port 4007');
});
```

Comment: Share routing configuration of angular app.

Comment: Hitting refresh makes a GET request to your express server. Angular on other hand uses History push. So there is conflict.

Comment: Hi @techierishi how can it be solved

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to solve the problem.

```
const routes = require('express').Router();

routes.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../client/dist/projectname/index.html'));
});
```